# Using ddclient in Whonix?

Tags: configuration, whonix, dns, ssh, server

Can we use `ddclient` with noip.com (or other ddns services) inside a Whonix VM to connect with our media servers or SSH ports?

I know pointing an .onion at our local server makes more sense, but I'm working on something that can't be done over onions.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot directly have an incoming clearnet IP. I.e. you cannot use the public clearnet IP of a Tor exit relay to anonymously host a server.

Explanation on incoming connections / opening ports:
https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Ports

Indirectly works by using VPN with Remote Port Forwarding or pagekite. See:
https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Hosting_Location_Hidden_Services

Disclaimer:
I am a maintainer of Whonix

Answer (score 0):

This kind of situations is soved as simple as it sounds: use OpenVPN *as an onion service*, and inside a fully-functional and feature-rich VPN segment do whatever you wish